# Dark Souls 2 Estoc infusion

Tags: dark-souls-2

Okay, I have no clue about infusions (yes, I've read all the summaries about each and I understand what they do but I have low faith and int and most don't apply to me). My stats are 40 STR and 40 DEX. I have an Estoc which has an E scaling in both STR and DEX. If I leave it uninfused, it does 210 damage I believe (it's a +10). If I add Raw to it, it does 241 damage. So, in my head I'm thinking Raw is the best infusion, but am I missing something? Should I leave it uninfused and just use resins or should I infuse it with raw and use resins and it would be even better? I guess I just don't understand the scaling and what it would mean.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Upgrades) about the Raw Infusion:

> Upgrades weapon physical base power, **decreases stat scaling**, weapon can be enchanted with temporary weapon effects. **Best used on weapons that have very low scaling to begin with as weapons that rely on their scaling for damage will most likely lose damage** by choosing this infusion. It can also be effective when a player knows that they won't be getting their stats high enough for the weapon's scaling to truly shine.

Most Infusions have this effect, though some not as great as the Raw infusion. Some even boost certain stat scaling, particularly Lightning, Magic and Dark, (while they might reduce base scaling, they will *add* FAI/INT/FAI & INT scaling respectively)

Since the Estoc has an E/E scaling in STR/DEX, using the Raw Infusion on it won't change anything. But, as an added bonus, you can still use resins on Raw/Mundane Infused weapons, which adds a base +50 elemental damage depending on the resin.

Comment: If the weapon scales well (B - S) and you're planning on levelling very high, you will benefit more from the scaling if you left it un-infused. If you're not planning on levelling very high OR the weapon has poor to no scaling, raw is a great enchantment to have. My boss farming build has 70+ str and uses power stanced raw malformed skulls +10. It's able to hit over 1200 on ng+15 giant lord using aromatic ooze and crystal magic weapon. I've tried this with power stanced clubs and greatswords, but neither could hold a candle to the raw skulls.